# Return Javascript function within document.write('<a href="">')

Tags: javascript, document.write

I have this javascript:

```
document.write('<a HREF="javascript:return validateForm();' + thisform + '.submit();void(0);"');
```

I also have the following function, referencing a form on my website.

```
function validateForm()
{
var y=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;

if (y==null || y=="")    {
alert('Please enter your email to continue.');
return false;
    }
}
```

Now how do I get that return in the HREF to work!? It won't return false in the case that the input equals "" and validateform() returns false.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with JS inside the `href`, but won't returning `validateForm()` *at all* prevent the form from being submitted? http://jsfiddle.net/fpYXY/

Comment: It doesn't! the php carries on as usual! The problem is I use an image as a submit, and it uses an href as well so that I can have a rollover image change. The href submits the form and returns the validate, but only before running the php anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Your code:

```
document.write('<a HREF="javascript:return validateForm();' +
  thisform + '.submit();void(0);"');
```

Seems incomplete. If you are using a link, then the href should link to a useful resource. If not, use a button or some other UI object that clearly indicates what will occur.

Returning false using the javascript pseudo protocol for the href attribute does nothing. The void statement does nothing at all (that is the point of void). Also, void is an operator so no need to include the grouping operator ().

You can't use an A element like this to conditionally submit the form, you really should be using the form's submit event to conditionally allow or prevent the submit. You can do:

```
document.write(
  '<a href="http://useful.com" onclick="return validateForm(' +
      thisform + ');">do stuff<\/a>');
```

Then within the *validateForm* function you can conditionally call the submit method of the form.

If *validateForm* returns false, the browser will not follow the link.

A far better strategy is to put the listener on the form:

```
<form onsubmit="return validateForm(...)" ...>
```

If validation fails, return false and the submit will be cancelled. Otherwise, the submit will continue.

Comment: Okay, RobG seems to have the right idea here, but there's a problem.
I already use onsubmit! I check with that function, it returns false and yet the submit continues, handling the submit with the php script I've created. How do I stop this? Is the return false not working??

Answer (score 1):

In order to control the form submission appropriately, you should have this kind of solution:

```
 document.write('<a href="#" onclick="submitMyForm(' + thisForm + ');"');
```

Then have this JS function:

```
function submitMyForm(theForm) {
    var y = theForm["email"].value;

    if (y==null || y=="")    {
        alert('Please enter your email to continue.');
    } else {
        theForm.submit(); // will only submit the form if it's valid
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have

```
alert("Not a valid e-mail address.");
document.location = "http://www.snarephoto.com/about/";
stopnow()
return false;
```

I think you should only have..

```
alert("Not a valid e-mail address.");
return false;
```

Also, what does stopnow do in your case?

Comment: Stopnow() is a function to replicate the stop button. Freezes the current window location. Yeah the document.location is unnecessary but it's just things I've been trying in an attempt to AVOID the form submitting to the *.php file listed in the form ACTION="" field.

Comment: If you are still having the same problem, you should try `alert(y);` just before you check `if y == ''`

Comment: Sticking in an alert(y) won't change the return status or functionality of the javascript within the HREF, will it @amitchd?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you don't have to return a function inside a href, but this is really non recommended.

I'm not really answering your question. But I can not figure out what the situation would be truly necessary to use it out instead of Javascript OOP.

I strong recommend to adapt your code to a non obstrusive way like that.

Body:

```
<p><a href="#" id="myLink">Item 1</a></p>
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myFunction=function(){
    //do something
    alert('You clicked me!');
    alert('This function is inside '+this.innerHTML+' Link');

    this.style.backgroundColor='Yellow';
}

document.getElementById('myLink').onclick=myFunction;
</script>
```

This not call the function directly, a reference in memory is created (like pointers in C) in the Virtual Machine. and the most important NONE EVAL is used, and are much faster then inline eval.